# How to retrieve all the content of calls made to a mock?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I'm writing a unit test for a function that takes an array of dictionaries and ends up saving it in a CSV.  I'm trying to mock it with pytest as usual:

```
csv_output = (
    "Name\tSurname\r\n"
    "Eve\tFirst\r\n"
)
with patch("builtins.open", mock_open()) as m:
    export_csv_func(array_of_dicts)

assert m.assert_called_once_with('myfile.csv', 'wb') is None
[and here I want to gather all output sent to the mock "m" and assert it against "csv_output"]
```

I cannot get in any simple way **all the data** sent to the mock during the *open()* phase by `csv` to do the comparison in bulk, instead of line by line.  To simplify things, I verified that the following code mimics the operations that `export_csv_func()` does to the mock:

```
with patch("builtins.open", mock_open()) as m:
  with open("myfile.csv", "wb") as f:
    f.write("Name\tSurname\r\n")
    f.write("Eve\tFirst\r\n")
```

When I dig into the mock, I see:

```
>>> m
<MagicMock name='open' spec='builtin_function_or_method' id='4380173840'>
>>> m.mock_calls
[call('myfile.csv', 'wb'),
 call().__enter__(),
 call().write('Name\tSurname\r\n'),
 call().write('Eve\tFirst\r\n'),
 call().__exit__(None, None, None)]
>>> m().write.mock_calls
[call('Name\tSurname\r\n'), call('Eve\tFirst\r\n')]
>>> dir(m().write.mock_calls[0])
['__add__'...(many methods), '_mock_from_kall', '_mock_name', '_mock_parent', 'call_list', 'count', 'index']
```

I don't see anything in the MagickMock interface where I can gather all the input that the mock has received.

I also tried calling `m().write.call_args` but it only returns the last call (the last element of the `mock_calls` attribute, i.e. `call('Eve\tFirst\r\n')`).

Is there any way of doing what I want?

Comment: Have you tried `.call_args_list`?

Comment: I'm also not sure what calls you're looking to check. `mock_calls` is returning you a pretty good list there. Are you looking for something more? The last thing you mention is from `.write`. If you switch to `m().write.call_args_list`, does that give you what you're looking for?

Comment: @wholevinski: `.call_args_list` yields the same output as `.mock_calls`, an that gives a list of `call()` objects.  What I need is an easy way to compare a list of strings with the content of the calls in the mock object.

Comment: Understood, answer posted with what I think solves your issue.

Comment: Added another edit that shows how you can pull the args out of a `mock.call` object as well.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can create your own `mock.call` objects and compare them with what you have in the `.call_args_list`.

```
from unittest.mock import patch, mock_open, call

with patch("builtins.open", mock_open()) as m:
    with open("myfile.csv", "wb") as f:
        f.write("Name\tSurname\r\n")
        f.write("Eve\tFirst\r\n")

# Create your array of expected strings
expected_strings = ["Name\tSurname\r\n", "Eve\tFirst\r\n"]
write_calls = m().write.call_args_list
for expected_str in expected_strings:
    # assert that a mock.call(expected_str) exists in the write calls
    assert call(expected_str) in write_calls
```

Note that you can use the assert call of your choice. If you're in a unittest.TestCase subclass, prefer to use `self.assertIn`.

Additionally, if you just want the arg values you can unpack a `mock.call` object as tuples. Index 0 is the *args. For example:

```
for write_call in write_calls:
    print('args: {}'.format(write_call[0]))
    print('kwargs: {}'.format(write_call[1]))
```

Comment: Yes!  I literally found this 20 minutes ago, tested that works, and I was going to post it as well.  It's very reassuring to know that we agree on the approach! :-)  In essence, instead of extracting the strings from the mock, go the other way around and compare something that is more native to the mock.  Thank you!

Comment: Awesome, glad you figured it out! I also added a way to pull the args out of a `mock.call` object as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had to it this way (Python 3.9). It was quite tedious just to get the mock-args out of the function.

from somewhere import my_thing

```
@patch("lib.function", return_value=MagicMock())
    def test_my_thing(my_mock):
         my_thing(value1, value2)
         (value1_call_args, value2_call_args) = my_mock.call_args_list[0].args
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you can't patch `builtins.open.write` directly since the patch within a with would need to enter the patched method and see that `write` is not a class method.

There are a bunch of solutions and the one I would think of first would be to use your own mock. See the example:

```py
class MockOpenWrite:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.res = []

    # What's actually mocking the write. Name must match
    def write(self, s: str):
        self.res.append(s)

    # These 2 methods are needed specifically for the use of with.
    # If you mock using a decorator, you don't need them anymore.
    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        return


mock = MockOpenWrite
with patch("builtins.open", mock):
    with open("myfile.csv", "w") as f:
        f.write("Name\tSurname\r\n")
        f.write("Eve\tFirst\r\n")

        print(f.res)
```

In that case, the res attribute is linked to the instance. So it disappears after the `with` closes.
You could eventually stored results somewhere else, like a global array, and check the results beyond the end of `with`.

Feel free to play around with your actual method.